# Failed to discover OP endpoint

Tags: node.js, passport.js, endpoint

I've ported sample yahoo passport code to my project. Always get "Failed to discover OP endpoint" error, when click on "Sign On with Yahoo" link.
whats the problem?

error is in this line (line 248):

```
this._relyingParty.authenticate(identifier, false, function(err, providerUrl) {
  if (err || !providerUrl) { return self.error(new InternalOpenIDError('Failed to discover OP endpoint URL', err)); }
      self.redirect(providerUrl);
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error using the `passport-google` module. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: For me, the problem was that `passport-google` uses OpenID, which Google no longer supports. I think Yahoo has dropped support for OpenID as well, since there is an OAuth module for Yahoo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-yahoo-oauth2